# Binding color to constants class

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, color, const

Не могу прибиндить цветовую константу, которая находится в другой dll-ке.

```
<GradientStop Offset="1" Color="{Binding Source={x:Static Member=constants:ColorConstants.Black}}"/>"/>
```

Студия ругается на плохой код и  не хочет ничего делать. И принимает только объект, а стринг не хочет. Как я понял, нужен конвертер.

Есть ли стандартный, или самому писать? (если можно, пример).

Comment: примеры привязок [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ссылки на статические свойства нужно давать не через `Binding`, а через `x:Static`:

```
<GradientStop Offset="1" Color="{x:Static constants:ColorConstants.Black}"/>
```

При этом у вас, разумеется, должно быть правильно объявлено пространство имён `constants`, что-то вроде

```
xmlns:constants="clr-namespace:Namespace.In.Assembly;assembly=Your.Assembly.Name"
```

Не забудьте убедиться, что ваша сборка с константами называется `Your.Assembly.Name`, в ней в пространстве имён `Namespace.In.Assembly` находится `public`-класс `ColorConstants`, у которого есть статическое свойство (а не поле!) `Black`, у которого хотя бы getter объявлен как `public`.

---

Для случая, когда ваш `x:Static` обладает неправильным типом (у вас строка, а ожидается `Color`), вам нужно применить конвертер. Самый простой синтаксически способ — написать свой `MarkupExtension` в замену `x:Static`, который заодно конвертировал бы значение в нужный тип стандартным конвертером.

Итак:

```
public class SmartStaticExtension : StaticExtension
{
    public SmartStaticExtension(string member) : base(member)
    {
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        // получим значение стандартного x:Static
        object value = base.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);

        // попытаемся вычислить тип, к которому надо привести
        IProvideValueTarget target =
            serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget)) as IProvideValueTarget;
        if (target != null)
        {
            Type targetType = typeof(object);
            // если целевое свойство - DependencyProperty
            DependencyProperty dp = target.TargetProperty as DependencyProperty;
            if (dp != null)
            {
                targetType = dp.PropertyType; // берём тип у него
            }
            else
            {
                // целевое свойство - обыкновенное свойство, используем рефлексию
                PropertyInfo pi = target.TargetProperty as PropertyInfo;
                if (pi != null)
                    targetType = pi.PropertyType;
            }

            // получаем стандартный конвертер:
            TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(targetType);
            // и конвертируем
            value = converter.ConvertFrom(value);
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

Имея такой конвертер, можно написать

```
<GradientStop Offset="1" Color="{local:SmartStatic constants:ColorConstants.Black}"/>
```

(разумеется, пространство имён `local` должно указывать туда, где определён `SmartStaticExtension`).

Работает как со строками (`"LightCyan"`) так и с RGB-константами (`"#708090"`).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34029/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd-binding-color-to-constants-class).